# Python | 26 lists called a-z, string with every letter, random letter is choosen, how to select the list

Tags: python, list, random

I have 26 lists called a,b,c,..,z and a string called letters.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Now I randomly choose a letter out of that string.

```
start_letter = random.choice(letters)
```

The value of **start_letter** should now be one letter, which is a list in my script.
Now, how do I select that list and randomly choose a "slot" in that list?

Comment: Why not have 1 dictionary with 26 keys rather than 26 separate variables?

Comment: You can also use `string.ascii_lowercase` for the string of letters

Comment: I don't understand you. I have 26 lists with different content and one string containing 26 letters. Where should I use the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a dictionary which has keys which are the letters of the alphabet and values which are the lists.
    letters_dict = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], ...}

and then you can get a random list with:

```
letters_dict[random.choice(letters)]
```

*Note that, although it is terrible practice, you can get a dictionary of the current local variables (with entries of the form variable_name:variable_value) with the `locals()` function and then select the random letter, as in: `locals()[random.choice(letters)]`, but a dictionary is definitely the right way to go.*

---

As for choosing a random "slot" in that list, you have two options, either randomly generate an index:

```
lst[random.randint(0,len(lst)]
```

or randomly select an element as you have done a letter:

```
random.choice(lst)
```

The first method has the advantage that you can use that index later if required, but the second is more readable if the index is not required.